# Why does adding an enclosing "" around a directory path give ERROR_INVALID_NAME (123) for CreateDirectory()?

Tags: c++, winapi

My directory name is `C:\Users\Some User\Desktop\test`. I added an enclosing "" because I recall that Windows would end up searching for `C:\Users\Some` without it.

However, in the case of `CreateDirectory()`, the function returned an ERROR_INVALID_NAME when using the enclosing "".

In contrast, it successfully created the directory WITHOUT the "". Could someone tell me why?

Here is the code that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    if (!::CreateDirectoryW(L"C:\\Users\\Some User\\Desktop\\test", nullptr))
    {
        printf("ERROR %lu", ::GetLastError());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the one that returns the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    if (!::CreateDirectoryW(L"\"C:\\Users\\Some User\\Desktop\\test\"", nullptr))
    {
        printf("ERROR %lu", ::GetLastError());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quotes are for the shell. The kernel doesn't use or understand them.

Comment: Windows is not a monolithic entity. The parts of Windows that treats spaces as special are the command processing parts, e.g. the CMD shell and the power shell. These parts of Windows have to *parse* commands and use spaces to delineate different parts of a command. That why you have to quote space containing strings. In contrast you are dealing with the *kernel*. Windows knows that the string passed to `CreateDirectoryW` is a path. Spaces are no different to any other character, and therefore quoting is incorrect.